# Android: MenuScene with AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am new of AndEngine and I am trying to create a scene with a menu with just one button item consisting of just a label.

Here is the code

```
public class TestActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    Camera mCamera;
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
    {
        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true,
                                 ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
                                 new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                                 mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene()
    {
        //Scene scene = new Scene();
        //scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0));
        //Entity layer = new Entity();
        //scene.attachChild(layer);

        Font mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(),
                                        this.getTextureManager(),
                                        256, 256,
                                        Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD),
                                        32);
        mFont.load();

        //Text centerText = new Text(100, 40, mFont, "Hello AndEngine!\nYou can even have multilined text!", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        //layer.attachChild(centerText);

        TextMenuItem playText = new TextMenuItem(1, mFont, "TEXT_TO_DISPLAY",
                                                 this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        MenuScene ms = new MenuScene(); 
        ms.addMenuItem(playText);
        ms.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0));
        //ms.buildAnimations();
        //ms.setBackgroundEnabled(false);

        ms.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        //scene.attachChild(ms);

        return ms;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem,
                                     float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The application crashes and I can't get how to fix it

here is the log cat stack trace

```
11-09 07:57:17.670: E/dalvikvm(3960): GC_EXPLICIT freed 186K, 42% free 8192K/13955K, paused 21ms+64ms, total 212ms
11-09 07:57:17.900: E/dalvikvm(3960): GC_EXPLICIT freed 68K, 42% free 8172K/13955K, paused 118ms+33ms, total 179ms
11-09 07:57:17.910: W/dalvikvm(3960): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4187c438)
```

I have noticed that if I uncomment buildAnimations() I get a nullPointer exception

Comment: show stack trace in logcat.

Comment: logcat info please, then we may dig down to the problem.

Comment: In your code, you only use default constructor of class `MenuScene`, and you didn't associate a camera to it (use `setCamera()`). Or you can try to use other constructors of `MenuScene`.

Comment: thanks a lot! if you post the answer I would be glad to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AndEngine, `MenuScene` extends the `CameraScene`, and in order to make `CameraScene` work properly, it needs a reference to the Camera object.

If you use default constructor to create the MenuScene object, you need to setup the Camera  object (via `setCamera()` method) before AndEngine starting to update the scene (which will require a valid camera object).
Or you can directly use other constructors with Camera parameter.